# Issue with AJAX calls on IE8 (CO customized version), jquery 1.7.2

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I have an issue with some (Windows 7 32 bit) machines which run IE8 (this customized version, ends with CO)...
What seems to be happening is that some of the ajax calls I am making do not return. They don't raise an error, or success, they simply don't come back to be processed.
Actually, I take it back, they do (Fiddler sees everything comes back), but it seems that the ajax events associated with the calls do not get triggered.

This is the code that should be able to trap any errors or success. I use deferreds to handle a spinner that shows on the screen to provide feedback about data being downloaded. Again, I use jquery 1.7.2.

```
$(document)
    .ajaxSend( function(e,xhr,opt) {
      //for each xhr send, there will be an error or success
      //we will hide the spinner in the .always event
      var prom = xhr.promise();
      prom.always(function() {
            commons.ajaxSessionCounts -= 1;
            //console.log(opt.url + "~~~RESPONSE");
            if ( commons.ajaxSessionCounts <= 0 ) {
                if (commons.ajaxSpinner == "nonblock") {                
                    $("#ajaxSpinnerImage").hide();
                } else {
                    $.unblockUI();            
                }              
        }
      }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, data) {
        var errorDetail = jqXHR.responseText;
        var errorHTML =
                "Error calling " + opt.url 
                + "<BR/>"
                + (textStatus || 'Unknown')
                + ": "
                + (data || 'missing data')
                + " - "
                + jqXHR.statusText
                + "<BR/>" + errorDetail;
        ShowMessage("AJAX ERROR", errorHTML, true);
      });

      commons.ajaxSessionCounts += 1;

      if (commons.ajaxSpinner == "nonblock") {
        $("#ajaxSpinnerImage").show();                  
          //console.log(opt.url + "~~~REQUEST");
      } else {
          $.blockUI({ 
              theme: true,                  
              baseZ: 15001,
              message: '<h3 style="text-align: center">' + 
                  '<img src="../resources/lib/images/ajax-loader.gif" />' + 
                  '<br>Please wait...</h3>' +
                  (opt.xhrFields && opt.xhrFields.displayMsg ? '<br>' + opt.xhrFields.displayMsg : '')
                  });            
      }
});
```

On some of the machines, we could run Reset IE settings from IE Tools menu and that fixed the problem. Don't ask why, I don't know. On some other machines, though, that solution didn't work.

IE11, IE10, IE9, Chrome, Opera have no issues running the code. Also, IE8 non customized had no issues.

I spent hours trying to figure out what's happening. Any suggestion is welcomed.

Thanks a bunch for taking a look at this.

Comment: Does the always callback always occur, even when you're having issues? i don't see where you're binding to the success handler.

Comment: When it doesn't work, are you even getting to this line: `var prom = xhr.promise();`

Comment: no, the callback doesn't always occur...I have 20 ajax calls on the initialization of the page, 17 work (callback happens) and 3 don't (nothing gets triggered)

Comment: If nothing is getting triggered at all, a javascript error must be occurring, which should be easily visible using the browser's console.

Comment: The ajaxSend happens for all calls...the returns (callbacks) do not fire for some of them...the effect on the page is the ajaxSessionCounts never comes back to 0, therefore the spinner shows up for ever...code finishes execution...UI becomes responsive....then, when I continue working in the UI, another set of ajax calls will work, and then another one fails...

Comment: I turned on javascript errors, nothing errors, that's the weird thing

Comment: why would an IE reset settings fix this on some of the machines? I was thinking an IE add-on...but then I disabled everything, entered incognito mode, nothing...

Comment: Are you working with domains that are within a local intranet (in other words, are the ip addresses of the server and remote servers all internal ip addresses?) in IE, sites that are in the intranet are handled differently, usually by going to compatibility mode forcing IE7 mode.

Comment: by the way, no success handler is needed for me here...this is global ($(document))...after these fire, I have some other things binding to the ajax events...(jqgrid mainly)

Comment: I was basically confirming that by *"success"* you really meant *"complete"* or "*always*" which are different in that they are called regardless of whether or not the request failed.

Comment: always is there...prom.always(function...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...there were some hidden javascript errors in another portion of the code that were causing the ajax events to not trigger anymore...
The most interesting thing about the javascript errors is that they were not bubbling up to be caught when "disable script debug" option was off in Internet Explorer.

The actual javascript error issue is described here (44,000 results):
http://www.bing.com/search?q=innertext+vs+textcontent&qs=AS&form=QBRE&pq=innertext&sc=8-9&sp=3&sk=AS2

I still don't understand why running IE reset settings fixed the issue on some machines.
In any case, thank you all who took a look at this.